# Devise + Omniauth-Facebook get user's phone #

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise for authentication in my Rails 3.2 app and am having trouble configuring `omniauth-facebook` to get the new user's phone number.

First of all: I'm not even sure that it's possible to get a phone number, so if that's the case and someone knows for sure, I'd be happy just for a confirmation.

It doesn't appear from https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook that "phone" is part of the FB auth hash by default, though the general Omniauth schema does have .info.phone (not required, of course). So my first idea was that it's a FB permissions problem. I'm not sure what permissions to use, though, as the [Permissions with Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) page doesn't say where to find the phone value (maybe this means it's just not possible?).

I have `phone` as a required attribute on the User model, so when I try to get it through FB the new object never persists. It works fine without looking for a phone number.

My config file:

```
# /config/initializers/devise.rb

config.omniauth :facebook, 'FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET', scope: 'email,public_profile', display: 'page'
```

In my user model:

```
# user.rb

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.phone = auth.extra.raw_info.phone  # have also tried auth.info.phone
    end
  end
```

Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's currently no way to get a user's phone number from Facebook.

[Facebook's Graph API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user) lists all the user information that you can access via the API. A user's phone number is not on the list.

Also, to inspect the contents of the auth hash, add the following line of code at the beginning of your authentications/sessions/callbacks controller action:

```
render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
```

You'll see that there is no `phone` field at `auth.extra.raw_info` or `auth.info`.